# 'module' object has no attribute 'cmap' in cubehelix python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to use `cubehelix` in python however I've been getting simple problems which I don't think should be showing up. The code I'm using is the following:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import cubehelix`

`cx1 = cubehelix.cmap(reverse=True)
alplot = plt.imshow(rtotal_rotated,vmax=1100,extent[-21,19,23,-17],cmap=cx1)`

However the following error comes up when I run the code:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cmap'`

I know this can't be right since I'm simply following the code from this tutorial
http://www.ifweassume.com/2014/04/cubehelix-colormap-for-python.html

So I'm not sure why it's breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Very like that the script imports itself, i.e. your script is named `cubehelix.py`. So, if you have file named `cubehelix.py` in your current working directory, rename it to `my_cubehelix.py` and try again.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. when I rename the file and change everything in my file with respect to that it still doesn't work